# Imports not working on copying workspace from one system to the other

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE on Windows 10. I copied the Eclipse workspace from one system to the other. The system where I copied the workspace, there all projects open on Eclipse but 'import ' giving error(not able to import modules and libraries in the code);therefore error in all projects. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: go to "configure build path" and check if all the libraries path are correct.

Comment: When your imports are not working, then something with your build path setup is incorrect. There are many things that could go wrong when **copying** workspaces; so that is a practice that I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: Could you open your ".classpath"-File in the project root with a text editor, and post the contents here?

Comment: @piyush- do you mean the classpath in the environmental variables?

Comment: Also I was using jdk1.8.0_72 on previous system. On the new system I downloaded updated version of java i:e  jdk1.8.0_102 . Could this be the cause for the issue?

Comment: Ridhi , are the referenced libraries in the same place on both machines ? Do you use maven or a build tool that can resolve dependencies ? Have you tried exporting the eclipse project as an archive and importing it on your new machine ?

Comment: If you are using Maven in your project, then one point of mishap can be the location of your maven repository. Check here in Eclipse: `Window-->Preferences-->Maven-->User Settings`. See if you have provided correct *settings.xml* in 'User Settings' column. Since you have changed the system, you might need to update it accordingly.

Comment: @Dhaval Simaria- Checked In Eclipse:  Window-->Preferences-->Maven-->User Settings. It was updated automatically and shows correct location of maven repository.

Comment: The errors got resolved by going to Project>>Libraries>>Build Path>> Configure Build path>>Add library   and added the default JRE library(i:e jre1.8.0_101).

Also added the latest release versions of all dependencies in pom.xml